# Printer is printing double the amount of copies specified

Tags: printing, printer

One of our printers is printing double, if I print 2 pages of something, 4 come out. I have looked all around for a setting that causes this but no settings seems to relate to my issue. The printer is a **Brother L5200DW**. The number of copies setting is set to 1, as well as the Brother Printer Preferences window. Am I missing something?

**Edit:**

I know there's not alot of information to work with, my apologies, I just don't know what else I can say about the problem, ask me any questions that could help you find an answer.

Comment: If this is only for you and not other users, try reinstalling the printer driver and restart, test

Comment: Il give that a go, thanks. @John

Comment: You may also [Reset the Network Settings to the Factory Settings](https://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=hll5200dw_us_eu_as&faqid=faq00000105_500). Read the article and its warnings.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would check is the number of copies specified in the driver. I suspect that is set to 2, so the driver will produce 2 copies for every page sent to it.

Go to Devices & Printers > Printer Properties. Click the Advanced tab and then the Printing Defaults button. Check the quantity specified there.

If this is the problem, reinstalling the driver as suggested by @john may fix the problem, but I would suggest a full reinstall, after removing the driver from Devices & Printers > Print Server Properties, to ensure no data from the old driver is left.